# I use npm run build-css to update my tailwind css. Is there a way to make this done automatically?

Tags: reactjs, electron, tailwind-css

Every time I add a new class in the `className` of a react component, i need to go to the terminal and type `npm run build-css` in order for the classes to take effect.

What `npm run build-css` does is `"build-css": "npx tailwindcss build  -o src/styles/main.css",`.

Is there a way to not have to run the above command on every UI change I do? I have used tailwind css in nextjs by following the official guide and it updates on its own whenever I do a change in the UI.

My scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.build.config.js && electron --noDevServer . ",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development && craco start",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.build.config.js --mode production && craco build",
    "watch-css": "npx tailwindcss build -i src/styles/index.css -o src/styles/main.css --watch",
    "build-css": "npx tailwindcss build -o src/styles/main.css",
    "package-m1": "electron-forge package --arch=arm64 --platform=darwin",
    "package-intel": "electron-forge package --arch=x64 --platform=darwin",
    "package": "npm run package-m1 && npm run package-intel",
    "postpackage": "electron-packager ./ --out=./builds"
  },
```

Comment: Does `--watch` flag solves your problem? Like `npx tailwindcss build  -o src/styles/main.css --watch`

Comment: It does if I run the command on a new terminal while the app is running. I tried adding it in my build or start script but it doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka I have added my scripts in my question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine this command into your normal run command, I'm not sure if you're using a framework or not but if you go into you package.json and look at your normal run/start command you can edit that to include the tailwind build. Depending on if you are using a unix or windows environment it will be slightly different. For react it would look like this(I don't remember syntax for nextjs)

```
"start": "npx tailwindcss build -o src/styles/main.css && node scripts/start.js"
```

The above would be for windows and the below for unix

```
"start": "npx tailwindcss build -o src/styles/main.css & node scripts/start.js"
```

Comment: didn't work. I tried the above with -0 and I got `Specified input file -0 does not exist.`. Tried with `-o` but that only builds the classes when you run the app, not while doing changes to the UI. 

I updated my original q to make it more specific about the requirement.

Comment: If you run the app and make changes to it while it's running it should reflect them when you save. And it should be -o that was a typo.